# Eclipse XML catalog entry - dot in directory

Tags: eclipse, xmlcatalog

Is there a way how to location of XML catalog entry in Eclipse where location has dot in one of its directories, for example when location is `C:\Users\xyz\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.3.RELEASE`, Add XML Catalog Element popup gives me this message "`URI must not include '.' or '..'"`.

The problem is in .m2 directory (it has dot). Do I have to rename it or is there a way to get around the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a URI escape for a dot... %2E